# Will installing Ubuntu erase all the data from the existing Windows, despite using VirtualBox?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, virtualbox

I have Windows 10 and now I want to install Ubuntu using VirtualBox.

While installing Ubuntu, I'm getting a warning saying that to install I need to erase the disk, which will automatically will delete all the files and documents in all operating systems.

So, how can I install Ubuntu while keeping all my files & documents safe?

Comment: If you're install Ubuntu inside virtual box, the disk it will be referring to will be the *virtual disk* that is part of your VM (or *virtual machine*). Only if you write your Ubuntu install media to a thumb-drive and boot it, would it then be referring to a real disk (ssd/hdd). What will happen though will depend on your circumstances, and our understanding of it, but it reads to me as if you're talking about a *virtual* disk, and not real disk drive. If you just created the *virtual* disk, you'll be erasing nothing.

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting the warning message inside Ubuntu, it's ok!

It will only affect the "**virtual hard disk space**".  if you have provided any.

Just proceed, you'll be ok, take a look at the screen shot for how to make a virtual hard disk:

[image: Create Virtual Hard Disk dialog]